# data entry form in google sheet for multiple users not working when accessed simultaneously

Tags: google-sheets

I've created form in google sheet, so that multiple users can add data, modify & delete.

However, it is not working properly when multiple users are working on it simultaneously.

For an example, two people are working on the sheet. User A and User B. If user A is typing something user B is also able to see and user B will be able to enter the detail, but it will change the details which are being entered by user A. Technically same sheet is opened for both the users and details keeps on changing what users are changing.

Ideally, if user A is entering some details user B should not be able to see it and form should be blank or unique for user B, so that both the data won't clash. I want it to be like the way google form is there wherein form will be blank when any user is opening it. (I have tried google form for my work, but as there are too many drop downs google form takes time to load and work gets slow that the reason I am trying to find the option in google sheet).

[google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DbrYzOQ4-s2Lys1CNlSFLmiav9haxkwgKShkZSFwDW8/edit#gid=0)

Above is the google sheet which you can open and check the form and coding. Also, please test it with a different id to test for multiple users.
Let me know if there is any workaround for this. Also, let me know if you need any other details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*This just isn't possible. Sheets is meant to be a collaborative tool; what's edited by one person will ***always*** show up for others. You need to use a different tool, for example like a Google form for data entry, but having data not being edited in other open versions is just not workaroundable.*